# How can I build in an index/subscript condition when having a prod() term in a sum() term?

Tags: r, indexing, sapply

I have a mathematical syntax problem with my formula.

My intention is to impose a condition on j so that the prod() is only computed over all j but i.

**Sample Code**

```
v1 = c(1:3)
sum(sapply(seq_along(v1), function(i) 
  i * prod(sapply(seq_along(v1), function(j) 
    v1[j]*2))))
```

Where and how can I write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
v1 <- 1:3
sum(sapply(seq_along(v1), function(i) i * prod(2 * v1[-i])))
```

If `v1` is really just `1:3`, you could use simply `v1` instead of `seq_along(v1)`.

The idea here is that negative indices can be used to *exclude* elements from a vector. So, `v1[-i]` is `v1` with the ith element removed.

Note that R can do arithmetic with entire vectors. Therefore, instead of `sapply(seq_along(v1), function(j) 2 * v1[j])`, you can just write `2 * v1`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option

```
library(matrixStats)
sum(seq_along(v1)*colProds(2*matrix(v1, nrow=4, ncol=3)[-c(1,4),]))
#[1] 72
```